# Interfacing with elements of GUI from Mac OS X Lion 1.07

Tags: macos, osx-lion, mission-control

How do you interface with a lot of the things that make up the OS X GUI (in particular, Mission Control)? Apple doesn't seem terribly open to developers trying to mess with their stuff, so I can't seem to find a public API to it anywhere. Really, I just want to tweak a few things to my own preference.

I know it can't be impossible; I've seen third-party apps switch a thing or two around.

Thanks for any help!